# Tensorflow profiling timelines inconsistent with wall time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently developing and profiling a neural network in tensorflow on a GTX 1070. My first implementation turned out to be rather inefficient due to some expensive FFT ops.
The upper timeline in the attatched pic reveals that one training step takes about 115ms. A second (mathematically equivalent) implementation seems to consume much less time, one step takes under 10ms.

[timelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2djsH.png)
(Sorry, I am not allowed to post pics yet)

Surprisingly both methods take approx. the same time when measured in python via:

```
build model, get train_op...
sess = tf.Session()

import timeit
t = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(train_op)
dt = timeit.default_timer() - t
print(dt)
```

In both cases 100 runs take ~17s > 100*115ms > 100*10ms which is more than I would expect from the python overhead. 
The network is fed using queues but the results are the same directly feeding numpy arrays into the graph so I concluded the empyt queues cannot be the bottleneck.

The timelines are in principle recorded with the difference that I measure two runs:

```
build model, get train_op...
sess = tf.Session()

def write_timeline(path):
    from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(train_op, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)

write_timeline('timeline_1st_run.json')
write_timeline('timeline_2nd_run.json')
```

The first runs always take much longer than the corresponding following runs, is tensorflow doing some optimization here or allocating memory for the first time?

[timelines_first_runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtqdN.png)

Can someone explain these inconistent results?
Why does my second implementation take the same time measured in python when the profiling timeline shows that it should run much faster?

Answer (score 1):

First run can take longer because of global memory pool growing, PTX compilation and optimizations.

You could turn off some of the optimizations as follows

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=tf.GraphOptions(optimizer_options=tf.OptimizerOptions(opt_level=tf.OptimizerOptions.L0)))
```

However, PTX compilation can still add 1-2 seconds to the first run. So for profiling purposes people usually include a "pre-warming" run to run the same computation before profiling it.

Also, if your `train_op` is something like `assign` or `assign_add`, running `train_op` will fetch the result back into Python. Python<->TensorFlow memory transfers are not reflected in the timeline (grpc transfers are also missing, tracking [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4809)). For profiling purposes you could run the op and omit the Python transfer as follows

```
sess.run(train_op.op)
```

Comment: Turning off optimizations indeed speeds up the first run a little and makes the following runs a bit slower.
My train_op is generated by `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize(loss)` which certainly does something like `assign` internally. 
`sess.run(train_op)` returns `None`, am I right that this rules out the Python<->TensorFlow memory transfers as issue?
Calling `sess.run([loss, train_op])` takes a bit longer.

Could there be another reason why the two implementations take the same wall time?

Comment: Returning `None` would rule out Python memory transfer being an issue. Your efficient vs inefficient implementation seem to take similar time on timeline (500 vs 700 ms), how much discrepancy are you seeing in wall-clock time after pre-warming?

Comment: The first timelines from above are actually with pre-warming (10ms vs 110ms). Pre-warmed wall-clock times are 160ms and 170ms, measurements averaged over 1000 runs.

Comment: it's hard to tell without reproducible example, but perhaps you are doing some extra stuff in Python. Maybe your graph gets modified between run calls? You can run with -c cProfile and visualize results using snakeviz. That will tell you the time spent in TF_SessionRun which be close to what you see in timelines unless there's large numpy transfers in feed_dict